# Vim remap in paste mode

Tags: vim, paste, remap

Is there a possibility to remap in paste mode.

For example, I remapped `jk` to `<ESC>` in insert mode with `inoremap jk <esc>`, so I can easily exit normal mode. But when I'm in paste mode with `:pastetoggle` my remapping does not work anymore. I looked for the help with `:help map-modes` but could not find anything related to the paste mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `:help 'paste'`:

```
[...]
When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
        - mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to the fact that remappings don't work in paste mode is to use [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)'s <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>commands to paste. At least this way leaving insert mode with paste set will also set `nopaste` and you won't find yourself in paste mode when you don't want to be as much.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. It didn't help me as alas I use GNU screen and it has not support for bracketed xterm paste escape codes

(from https://coderwall.com/p/if9mda/automatically-set-paste-mode-in-vim-when-pasting-in-insert-mode)

```
:inoremap jj <esc>
:inoremap jk <esc>
let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[?2004h"
let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[?2004l"

" This resets paste mode after insert
inoremap <special> <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin()

function! XTermPasteBegin()
  set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
  set paste
  echo "DONE"
  return ""
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach I found. When you hit escape to leave insert mode it turns off paste mode automatically. Also the colors help you know which mode you are in. hth.

```
" Mode Indication -Prominent!
function! InsertStatuslineColor(mode)
  if a:mode == 'i'
    hi statusline ctermfg=red
  elseif a:mode == 'r'
    hi statusline ctermfg=blue
  else
    hi statusline ctermfg= magenta
  endif
endfunction

function! InsertLeaveActions()
  hi statusline ctermfg=green
  set nopaste
endfunction

au InsertEnter * call InsertStatuslineColor(v:insertmode)
au InsertLeave * call InsertLeaveActions()

" to handle exiting insert mode via a control-C
inoremap <c-c> <c-o>:call InsertLeaveActions()<cr><c-c>

" default the statusline to green when entering Vim
hi statusline ctermfg=green

" have a permanent statusline to color
set laststatus=2
```